# Problems receiving email

Tags: php, email

`function socketmail($to,$subject,$message,$headers,$debug=0)`

```
{global $MAILFROM;
$from=$MAILFROM;
 list($me,$mydomain) = split("@",$from);

// Now look up the mail exchangers for the recipient
 list($user,$domain) = split("@",$from,2);
 if(getmxrr($domain,$mx,$weight) == 0)  return FALSE;

// Try them in order of lowest weight first
array_multisort($mx,$weight);
$success=0;
    foreach($mx as $host) 
{
    // Open an SMTP connection
    //echo "$host To: $to<HR>";
    //print "SMTP: $host\n";

    $connection = fsockopen ($host, 25, &$errno, &$errstr, 1);
    if (!$connection)
        continue;
    $res=fgets($connection,256);
    if(substr($res,0,3) != "220") break;

    // Introduce ourselves
    fputs($connection, "HELO $mydomain\n");
    $res=fgets($connection,256);
    if(substr($res,0,3) != "250") break;

    // Envelope from
    fputs($connection, "MAIL FROM: $from\n");
    $res=fgets($connection,256);
    if(substr($res,0,3) != "250") break;

    // Envelope to
    fputs($connection, "RCPT TO: $to\n");
    $res=fgets($connection,256);
    //print "Response: $res\n";
    if(substr($res,0,3) != "250") break;

    // The message
    fputs($connection, "DATA\n");
    $res=fgets($connection,256);
    if(substr($res,0,3) != "354") break;

    // Send To:, From:, Subject:, other headers, blank line, message, and finish
    // with a period on its own line.
    fputs($connection, "To: $to\r\nFrom: $from\r\nSubject: $subject\r\n$headers\r\n\r\n$message\r\n.\r\n");
    $res=fgets($connection,256);
    if(substr($res,0,3) != "250") break;

    // Say bye bye
    fputs($connection,"QUIT\n");
    $res=fgets($connection,256);
    if(substr($res,0,3) != "221") break;

    // It worked! So break out of the loop which tries all the mail exchangers.
    $success=1;
    break;
}

 // Debug for if we fall over - uncomment as desired
if($debug) 
{
    print $success?"Mail sent":"Failure: $res\n";
    die(0);
}
if($connection) 
{
    if($success==0) 
        fputs($connection, "QUIT\n");
    fclose ($connection);
}
return $success?TRUE:FALSE;
```

There is the code. The problem is here :

```
fputs($connection, "RCPT TO: $to\n");
$res=fgets($connection,256);
//print "Response: $res\n";
if(substr($res,0,3) != "250") break;
```

If i change break with continue, it works, but i want to warning if an email is not sent. If i test this error the message is:  Failure: 553 sorry, that domain isn't in my list of allowed rcpthosts (#5.7.1).

Can you help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A 553 error happens when your mail server is restricted from being an open relay (which is a good thing or you could forward any email for anyone on the internet). Typically, when you use mail(), you're using your local server's MTA (if this is Linux, that would be sendmail). So your remote server can't be used to send your email in this way. Either that or you need to contact the remote server and either whitelist the server this script is running on (preferred) or allow the domains you're trying to send to in the relay (which could allow anyone to relay to those domains)

Out of curiosity, why aren't you using mail()? It would be much simpler than opening a raw socket.